# Indexes and Cypher - How to create a node that is indexed

Tags: neo4j

I am using in cypher from the console

```
create (SearchWord {word='car'})
```

That works in creating a node but how can I now find that node? I tried start n=node but it seems to want an index. From my create node how is the index created?

I know the index can be created manually but how then will the create node access the index?

Any ideas?

Comment: Neo4j 2.0:
`CREATE (:Thing {SearchWord:'car'});

MATCH node:Thing
WHERE node.SearchWord = 'car'
RETURN node;`

optionally:
`CREATE INDEX ON :Thing(SearchWord);`

Answer (score 5):

When you create a node like you did in your example, the (internal) ID of this node is returned, e.g. `1`. You can then access the node like this:

```
START n=node(1) RETURN n
```

However, it is not recommended to use the internal node IDs for anything but temporary access because they might change (at least this is the state I know). Thus, you have two (actually three, coming to this below) options to find your nodes later.

1. Connect your newly created nodes indirectly or directly to the reference node that always 
   has the id 0. Then you can access your nodes via graph traversal.
2. Create a (legacy; see below) index via the Java-API in a server extension or in your embedded Neo4j. This won't work with Cypher.

The good news is, as of Neo4j 2.x - i.e. currently Neo4j 2.0.0-M03 - there is a new automatic indexing feature that incorporates node labels. Here you can create an index regarding a pair of node label and node property. Each node that gets the label will be indexed on the respective property.

In Neo4j 2.0.0-M03 an index is created like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :<label>(<property>)
```

Then, you can get your node like this:

```
MATCH node:<label>
WHERE node.<property> = <value>
return node
```

I know this is a bit abstract here. I'd like to recommend you a few reads.

Documentation on the `START` Cypher clause: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-start.html
Documentation on the new "schema" indexes: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-schema-index.html

And finally some - as I find - very helpful slides concerning the schema indexes: http://www.neo4j.org/develop/labels, the second presentation (with title Labels and Indexes in Neo4j 2.0). There are some short and understandable examples.

I hope that gets you going!

Comment: It would really help if you could give an example of a cypher query, for example to create a node called SearchWord which had a property called word. And then that is indexed so I can query it.

Comment: You could have a look at http://www.terminalstate.net/2013/05/labels-and-schema-indexes-in-neo4j.html

Comment: According to the blog, the index can be created after the nodes were created. But does that mean the index will then index all future creations of nodes and past ones? My biggest issue with indexes is that I see so much conflicting information. I could not even get the create n: syntax to work but after dropping the n: it worked.

Comment: The problem is that we have a long history of index management. There are *legacy* indexes that are pre-2.0 and the new indexes that are introduced with Neo4j 2.0. And in the legacy indexes we have *manual* and *automatic* indexes.